# statistical test (wilcox or t-test, or any, really) in a "group_by" pipe

Tags: r, dplyr, stat

I have a dataset looking at water quality for various conditions. Here is a subset of the data (called `tempdf1`:

```
    Material Unit  Condition Rep Measurement
1    Bromine  ppm Unfiltered   1         4.0
2  Carbonate  ppm Unfiltered   1        80.0
3    Bromine  ppm Unfiltered   2         6.0
4  Carbonate  ppm Unfiltered   2       120.0
5    Bromine  ppm Unfiltered   3         6.0
6  Carbonate  ppm Unfiltered   3       100.0
7    Bromine  ppm   Filtered   1         0.0
8  Carbonate  ppm   Filtered   1       120.0
9    Bromine  ppm   Filtered   2         0.0
10 Carbonate  ppm   Filtered   2       100.0
11   Bromine  ppm   Filtered   3         0.5
12 Carbonate  ppm   Filtered   3       100.0
```

I would like to run a statistical test (I was leaning toward a t-test, but since my data size is not normally distributed, I was thinking of running a Wilcoxen test). However, no matter what I do, I can't run this successfully.

I'd like to group my tests by Material (Bromine, Carbonate) and then compare the measurements for "Unfiltered" against those that are "Filtered". However, I keep getting errors when I try to run this. I've restructured my data so that the measurements for "Unfiltered" & "Filtered" are in separate columns. Here is an example of how I've restructured the data, and the analysis I've tried to run:

```
tempdf2 <- tempdf1 %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(id_cols=c(Material,Rep),names_from=Condition,values_from=Measurement)
tempdf2 %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Material) %>%
  dplyr::summarize(w=wilcox.test(Filtered~Unfiltered,paired=FALSE)$p.value)
```

This is the error I receive

```
Error in `dplyr::summarize()`:
! Problem while computing `w = wilcox.test(Filtered ~ Unfiltered, paired = FALSE)$p.value`.
ℹ The error occurred in group 2: Material = "Carbonate".
Caused by error in `wilcox.test.formula()`:
! grouping factor must have exactly 2 levels
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I've read through a few articles about running various statistical tests using the "group_by" method first, but haven't been able to follow it. Would someone help me better understand how to run a statistical test (Ex: Wilcoxon) on a table that has been grouped by a specific variable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we are using the `formula` method, use the 'Condition' as independent variable - which is specified in `?wilcox.test`

> formula - a formula of the form **lhs ~ rhs** where lhs is a **numeric variable** giving the data values and rhs either 1 for a one-sample or paired test or a **factor with two levels** giving the corresponding groups. If lhs is of class "Pair" and rhs is 1, a paired test is done

```
library(dplyr) #version >= 1.1.0
tempdf1 %>%
   reframe(pvalue = wilcox.test(Measurement ~ Condition, 
     paired = FALSE)$p.value, .by = Material)
   Material    pvalue
1   Bromine 0.0721982
2 Carbonate 0.8136637
```

#### data

```
tempdf1 <- structure(list(Material = c("Bromine", "Carbonate", "Bromine", 
"Carbonate", "Bromine", "Carbonate", "Bromine", "Carbonate", 
"Bromine", "Carbonate", "Bromine", "Carbonate"), Unit = c("ppm", 
"ppm", "ppm", "ppm", "ppm", "ppm", "ppm", "ppm", "ppm", "ppm", 
"ppm", "ppm"), Condition = c("Unfiltered", "Unfiltered", "Unfiltered", 
"Unfiltered", "Unfiltered", "Unfiltered", "Filtered", "Filtered", 
"Filtered", "Filtered", "Filtered", "Filtered"), Rep = c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), Measurement = c(4, 
80, 6, 120, 6, 100, 0, 120, 0, 100, 0.5, 100)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can index using `Condition==<x>`, like this:

```
library(dplyr)

f <- \(m,c) wilcox.test(m[c=="Unfiltered"], m[c=="Filtered"])$p.value

df %>%
  group_by(Material) %>%
  summarize(pvalue=f(Measurement, Condition))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  Material  pvalue
  <chr>      <dbl>
1 Bromine   0.0722
2 Carbonate 0.814
```